# How can I generate a PDF from HTML without the PDFlib library?

Tags: php, pdf

I need to dinamicaly generate a PDF from HTML, but I have `PDF Support disabled` on my hosting, so is it possible to do without PDFlib GmbH library?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common alternative is [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). It is pure PHP and needs no installed extensions.

Answer (score 3):

There are many packages, but as I gather you're not able to install extra libs on your hosting. Options would be [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) if you feel like rewriting your whole HTML into blocks, [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) if you feel a bit less masochistic, which has some limited html/css support.

Comment: You should take TCPDF. It has almost every feature you need and it is very well documented.

Answer (score 2):

An other nice option is [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/), which is a HTML to PDF converter and is (almost) CSS 2.1 compliant. It can be used either using PDFLib or the R&OS CPDF class

Answer (score 0):

You could also checkout htmldoc:

[Project page](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1)

Comment: but it needs to be installed yes?
i haven't permission to install it on the hosting.